# I keep getting this error 'Manager isn't accessible via Post instances' in django 1.10

Tags: python, django

Here are my codes in **models.py**

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):            

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')
```

Comment: Your error is not caused by this code. Please show the full code you are using when you get this error, and the full traceback.

Answer (score -1):

A manager needs to be used with a model and not a queryset.

```
pm = PublishedManager() #in model
```

then if 'Post' is the model class

```
Post.pm.all()
```

You cant use objects or querysets of Post.